# Visual Studio's Format Document – How to Write it in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-4.0

I'm having a go at writing some C# code which overrides the Render method of the System.Web.UI.Page and then reformats the HTML before presenting it to the browser. This is purely experimental so overhead is not a concern right now.

I'm perhaps a little learned in the ways of the regular expression and would like to utilise them here, but I can't seem to think of a real concise and elegant way of nicely formatting a HTML document. I've managed to completely minify the HTML using regex, but as for correctly indenting it, I'm stumped.

So, if you had a string of HTML, using C#, how would you reformat it in much the same way as Visual Studio's Format Document function does? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to beautify the HTML that's being sent to the browser? The browser will ignore the formatting anyway.

Comment: You're right Mark, and as I alluded to this is something of an experiment. If it happens that it's trivial to accomplish, I would like to use it for work which I submit to HTML 5 galleries, for I have been featured on the odd occasion. The messy markup that .NET spews out would never be considered for these galleries, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). I have used [this .net wrapper](http://markbeaton.com/SoftwareInfo.aspx?ID=81a0ecd0-c41c-48da-8a39-f10c8aa3f931) quite successfully.

Comment: This certainly seems as though it would do the trick. I must confess, though, that I'm somewhat averse to using a library written in (portable ANSI) C _and_ a .NET wrapper just to accomplish this. The unwieldiness of this suggested solution far outweighs, in my opinion, the novelty of a nicely formatted document. I'd really rather do this in C# code or in nothing else, really.

Comment: @david - parsing and formatting html is not a trivial task. Ask anyone who has tried. Tidy is *a*, if not *the*, gold standard. I am not sure I understand your aversion to using code that works and has been accepted, refined and improved over the past 10 (+?) years, regardless of language or distributable. But then, it is not for me to question your motives.  Good luck with that.

Comment: I guess I have something of a minor disinclination to using other people's code unless absolutely necessary. It's especially difficult for me using a .NET wrapper called 'Mark.Tidy'. You are right, though, and I appreciate how difficult this task is by the the very token that I'm here asking how it's done! :-D I was just hoping that merely indenting the document correctly would be slightly simpler.

Comment: @David- so build it with whatever assembly name you like, or just add the source to your own project, as I have done in some cases. It works (tm)

Comment: @femaref - thanks for that. Perhaps I should have added a link to the project page in the first two words of the answer. ;-)